# sed - find string made of 4 numbers with a preceding character and append character

Tags: sed, regular-expression

I'm trying to build a `sed` command that will allow me to search and replace some values in a large csv file.
I have this column which contains years, like `2005 - 2006` `2001 - 2003` and so on, but I also have some errors in it that left the csv file with many cells that contains `-2001` `-2010` `-1998` and so on. 
What I want to do is move the `-` character at the end of the string, like `-2001` becomes `2001-` and so on. The pattern is the same in all affected cells, all the values are made of character `-` + the year made of 4 numbers.

```
sed -e "^-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]"
```

I'm new to regex and currently some using tutorials.

Answer (score 2):

```
sed -e "s/^-\([0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]\)/\1-/" file.csv
```

The part between `\(` and `\)` is referenced in the replacement part by `\1`, allowing to replace by "whatever matched the search".

Note that if you are using a csv file, this will only work if the column is really the first one (`^` matches the beginning of the line). If the column is somewhere else, you might want to use

```
sed -e 's/\(,[[:space:]]*\)-\([0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]\)/\1\2-/' file.csv
```

instead. (detecting the column start by a comma possibly followed by spaces, then reusing that start in the replacement.)

Comment: If we told about years the regex can be shorter: `20[01][0-9]` if you don't like `[0-9]\{4\}`